# ejabberdctl not found in bash Ubuntu(installing ejabberd)

Tags: ejabberd, erlang

Here is the site I tried to use as a manual:

[How To Install eJabberd XMPP Server on Ubuntu | DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ejabberd-xmpp-server-on-ubuntu)

I was trying to install ejabberd with applying the tutorials in many site to my VM which is ubuntu but I am stuck in the beginning. After I wrote

```
sudo  apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install ejabberd
```

it installs ejabberd. But when I try to write the following

```
ejabberdctl register admin localhost mypassword
```

it says ejabberdctl not found. I also tried to restart it with but it is still same.

```
sudo service ejabberd restart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ejabberdctl` is owned by root with 550 permissions installed in `/usr/sbin` meaning that non-root users can not execute the binary. Try:

```
sudo ejabberdctl register admin localhost mypassword
```

`sudo` elevates your privileges to root in that terminal (after entering a password) thus giving you access to the binary.

Comment: I have tried but sudo: ejabberdctl: command not found